# Why 2D linear interpolation formula sums the initial point's y component?

Tags: interpolation

$$y=y1+(x-x1)\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$$
https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/linear_interpolation.html

I've seen this formula in multiple places and I'm wondering why do we need to multiply the distance between $x$ and $x1$ to the slope and add it to $y1$ when this formula would work just the same:
$$y=x\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$$

Comment: That other formula does definititely *not* work just the same (unless the line happens to pass through the origin). Have you tried plugging in some numbers to see what happens?

Comment: I actually tried pluging in numbers but only the ones that cross the origin. I think that answered my question.

Comment: OK, sounds good. :-)

Comment: If you want to make this into an answer I'll accept it. Considering the origin wasn't very intuitive to me at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formulas only give the same result if the line goes through the origin. The first formula is the correct one.